# How to secure Nodejs / express API used in an another application running under different server

Tags: node.js, express, authentication, jwt

Actually I want to know that, what is the best way to secure my node js / express API from another application in which I'm calling the API from client side (Ajax call). 
 I know that, I could use JWT token based authentication, but I need to pass the  Username and password to Node server to get token generated, I don't want to do this as I've already logged-in in an another application.

Any help / suggestions would be appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

So, you need to work with some Oauth server and your application before process the request sent to him must validate de token on that server.

But how it works?

In short terms, must exist in your application a middleware who will do a request to oauth server, after you receive that response (if will not with authentication error), you continue the process. If to exist a problem with the token or login, the oauth has the responsibility to block the process and return HTTP status 401 (when the user and pass wrong) or 403 (when the user doesn't have the permission to the resource).

[Here](https://github.com/oauthjs/express-oauth-server) are a few examples to follow.